# display countries based on selection of id from a complex JSON structure using Javascript Map or Filter Method

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JSON structure which is bit complex and I want to display the corresponding items based on the selection of Id. For example, in my JSON structure I have the sections of continent and under each continent countries are listed within the property names "Levels".So, I want to filter each continent based on the id from the "Levels" property.
So, if the "Country.Level.Id === 6" it should display the Country.Name="America". I have been trying to make it work by using JavaScript Map and Filter method but couldn't make it work.

Here is my SandBox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-feather-ugvxv?file=/src/index.js:0-1294

The data:

```js
const items = [
  {
    Country: [
      {
        Id: "1",
        Name: "Europe",
        Levels: [
          {
            Id: "1",
            Name: "Finland",
            DisplayName: "Finland"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Id: "1",
        Name: "ASIA",
        Levels: [
          {
            Id: "2",
            Name: "Bangladesh",
            DisplayName: "Bangladesh"
          },
          {
            Id: "3",
            Name: "India",
            DisplayName: "India"
          },
          {
            Id: "4",
            Name: "Pakistan",
            DisplayName: "Pakistan"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Id: "3",
        Name: "America",
        Levels: [
          {
            Id: "5",
            Name: "USA",
            DisplayName: "USA"
          },
          {
            Id: "6",
            Name: "Canada",
            DisplayName: "Canada"
          },
          {
            Id: "7",
            Name: "Australia",
            DisplayName: "Australia"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Id: "4",
        Name: "Africa",
        DisplayName: "Africa",
        Levels: [
          {
            Id: "8",
            Name: "Nigeria",
            DisplayName: "Nigeria"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

My coding attempt:

```js
const selectById = "5";
const countries = items[0].Country;
const result = countries.filter(item => item.Levels.Id === selectById);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your data structure, this function will find a continent from a country id:

```js
function findContinentByCountryId(items, id) {
  return items[0].Country.find((continent) => {
    return continent.Levels.some(country => country.Id === id)
  })
}
```

You can test it with the snippet below:

```js
function findContinentByCountryId(items, id) {
  return items[0].Country.find((continent) => {
    return continent.Levels.some(country => country.Id === id)
  })
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="country-id">Country id:</label>
  <input id="country-id">
  <input type="submit" value="Find continent by country id">
</form>

<span></span>

<script>
  const items = [
    {
      Country: [
        {
          Id: "1",
          Name: "Europe",
          Levels: [
            {
              Id: "1",
              Name: "Finland",
              DisplayName: "Finland"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          Id: "1",
          Name: "ASIA",
          Levels: [
            {
              Id: "2",
              Name: "Bangladesh",
              DisplayName: "Bangladesh"
            },
            {
              Id: "3",
              Name: "India",
              DisplayName: "India"
            },
            {
              Id: "4",
              Name: "Pakistan",
              DisplayName: "Pakistan"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          Id: "3",
          Name: "America",
          Levels: [
            {
              Id: "5",
              Name: "USA",
              DisplayName: "USA"
            },
            {
              Id: "6",
              Name: "Canada",
              DisplayName: "Canada"
            },
            {
              Id: "7",
              Name: "Australia",
              DisplayName: "Australia"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          Id: "4",
          Name: "Africa",
          DisplayName: "Africa",
          Levels: [
            {
              Id: "8",
              Name: "Nigeria",
              DisplayName: "Nigeria"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  const form = document.querySelector('form')
  const input = document.querySelector('input')
  const result = document.querySelector('span')
  
  form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const continent = findContinentByCountryId(items, input.value)
    result.textContent = continent ? continent.Name : 'Continent not found'
  })
</script>
```

### Side note

I don't know the context of your problem, but be aware that object properties are usually *camelCased* in javascript (instead of *PascalCased* in your case) and that `Country` and `Levels` might not be ideal names for the corresponding data. Furthermore, in case this wasn't intentional, Europe and Asia have the same id in your dataset.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions about the data structure. My original one is bit different than this,,,

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your filter method appropriately it'll work

```
countries.filter(item => item.Levels.find(elem => elem.Id === selectById))
```

[SandboxLink](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-bas-ze18v?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: probably I should learn more about using different methods, seems so easy here

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If so please upvote and accept as an answer!